# Temperature Ranges for MBP Battery. Any Information?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I don't mean the temperature of Environment: Office, Apartment, Weather etc.

Is it normal, that Battery has some 35 Celsius/95F at normal state
and 39C/102F while working/calculating?

Are there any References to the Ranges for the Temperature of MacBook Pro Battery?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is normal. In general, you do not need worry about temperatures of components of your Mac - unless you experiencing some form of crash or problem that stops you from doing the job with the software you intended.

Here's a link to the instructions from Apple regarding the battery and temperature concerns:

https://www.apple.com/am/batteries/maximizing-performance/

I.e. you should strive for the ambient temperature around your computer to be around 16° to 22° C as the ideal. Avoid ambient temperatures over 35° C or below 10° C.

When storing the computer (i.e. it is turned completely off), store it in temperatures -20° to 45° C.

Comment: "You do not need to worry about temperatures of components of your Mac" in bold text and underlined. ;-)

Comment: It's not answered my question. I have extra mentioned, that the question is not about the Temperature of the MacBook Pro Environment: Office, Apartment etc. You have answered the first part: whether 39C/102F is normal. May you please give any References about the "good" Temperature range for the Battery?

Comment: @MikroDel Why do you need it? what is the practical application here? - For all usual intents and purposes, you need to have your ambient temperature within those ranges, and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Here : https://www.apple.com/am/batteries/maximizing-performance/

> MacBook works best at 50° to 95° F (10° to 35° C) ambient temperatures. Storage temperature: -4° to 113° F (-20° to 45° C).

> It’s especially important to avoid exposing your device to ambient temperatures higher than 95° F (35° C)